# After updage wordpress 4.4 to 4.5 nginx config works not properly

Tags: permalinks, nginx

Permalinks (post name option) stop working (get 404 page with text "It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help.") after upgrade from 4.4 to 4.5. I use nginx as a webserver and here is my config file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        root /var/www/example;
        index index.php;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                        return 404;
                }
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location  ~ /\. {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                deny all;
        }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        error_log  /var/log/nginx/audreysoie_error.log error;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/audreysoie_access.log;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
}
```

When I switch to plaing links (on wordpress 4.5) - all pages works ok, but with permalinks - not.

I tried to google, modify this config but have no success. Could you advice what  config is correct?

Comment: And _what exactly_ does not work? You are not describing the actual problem… please file an [edit] and fix that.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "stop working" ? What precisely happens when link is clicked (output, status codes, etc) ?

Comment: @kaiser post updated. Is it clear now I need to describe in another way?

Comment: @Rarst I getting 404 page.

Comment: My goal is find correct config for latest wordpress version for nginx.

Comment: Sorry, you did not really clarify it. Do _what_ did you set your permalink settings? Also, do you have the problem inside `/wp-admin` or just in the public facing side of things? Or on both ends? Further: What PHP version are you using? And what Nginx version? What do you run on your server (Ubuntu, CentOS, …) and in which version? And what exactly is inside `fastcgi_params`?

Comment: Wait a second … why the heck are you using `rewrite` to **remove** `/wp-admin`? That will surely conflict with public routes. Remove that and see if it works again.